# Git issue: help on merging remote branches

Tags: git, git-merge

I am having a issue where I'd like to perform merge from a branch `lpls_merge_Qa` to `lpls_merge_dev`. I did a checkout of master branch and executed the below command:

```
C:\test\test_merge\lpls_merge_master>git merge lpls_merge_dev lpls_merge_qa
```

Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.

Soon after the merge I don't see any changes on dev stream. Please can you let me know how exactly can I verify my merge changes?

Answer (score 0):

Git could change only current branch (all commits, merges, etc are changing current HEAD only). I.e. you are saying that you checked out `master` branch, then it means `git merge lpls_merge_dev lpls_merge_qa` merges both branches into master (octopus merge). If you want merge into `lpls_merge_dev` you should first `git checkout lpls_merge_dev`, then `git merge lpls_merge_qa`.

Comment: I created three different folders for master,dev & QA branches. When i run git branch on master folder I see all the three branches but its not the same when i run the command from dev/QA folder.
C:\test\test_merge\lpls_merge_master>git branch
* lpls_merge_dev
  lpls_merge_qa
  master
C:\test\test_merge\lpls_merge_QA>git branch
* lpls_merge_qa
  master
C:\test\test_merge\lpls_merge_QA>git merge lpls_merge_dev
fatal: lpls_merge_dev - not something we can merge

Comment: @user2935115 Formatting of comment is pretty bad. Could you update your question with `git branch -a` in all folders? BTW, creating folders is not good practice for git, as it makes all things more difficult and decreases your performance.

Comment: I was able to do a successful merge by creating a single folder and switching between them using git checkout <branch name> . This resolved my issue.
Thanks